# How to run EC2 Ubuntu AMI on a Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Django Python application and I need to install some libraries, but using Amazon Linux (any version) I need to install a lot of libraries (it's very boring and it wastes a lot of time). Using EC2 Ubuntu AMI,I can install easily these libraries and only some of them (Amazon Linux will need a lot of them) and I want to run this Ubuntu AMI on my Elastic Beanstalk application, but I don't know how to do this.